# Hint/Error message for InputField (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input-field, hint

With Android/Java you can use something like this

```
myEditText.setError("This field cannot be blank");
```

to show an error message/hint for the entered text in an `EditText`:

[image]

Is there anything similar for Unity's `InputField` in C# or do you have to make your own (e.g. with a text that auto-vanishes after 5 seconds)?

Is there a commonly used design/layout to show a message like that in Unity/Windows games?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can make your own!

Add a new add a GameObject as a child to the GameObject your InputField is attached to.
You can edit this GameObject however much you want, but just adding a UnityEngine.UI.Text should be fine, and make sure that the new GameObject is not active by defualt.

Now add a script to the GameObject with your InputField, and add something like this to it:

```
public void OnStoppedEditing(string text) {
  if (text == "") { 
    errorWindow.SetActive(true); 
    errorText.text = "This field cannot be blank"; 

  }

}
public void Start() {
   //adds a listener that runs OnStoppedEditing when you stop editing myField
   myField.onEndEdit.AddListener(delegate {OnStoppedEditing(myField); }); 

   myField = gameObject.getComponent<InputField>();
   errorText = errorWindow.getComponent<Text>();
}
public GameObject errorWindow;
Text errorText; 
InputField myField;
```

make sure that you add "using UnityEngine.UI;" to the top of the script

Save the script and apply errorWindow to the child GameObject that you created!

Please note that I didnt test this code (I dont have access to a pc with unity right now) so if it has any errors just ask :)

Comment: Thanks! When is `OnStoppedEditing` being called? Do you have to press the "Submit" button or does it just wait a couple of seconds after you typed the last letter? I don't validate until the "save" button has been pressed, so my code looks a bit different (I just use the `onClick`), plus I also added a red Outline to the InputField and disable it again when the "save" button is pressed the next time if everything's okay.

Comment: OnStoppedEditing is being called right when you click out of the field. And if you only want the box to appear you can just use  `errorWindow.SetActive(true); 
    errorText.text = "This field cannot be blank";`

Comment: Just to be clear, OnStoppedEditing is only being called because of 
 `myField.onEndEdit.AddListener(delegate {OnStoppedEditing(myField); }); `

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarifying. What I ended up with: A click on "Save" calls the validation method. If a password but no username was entered, a red Outline around the InputField is added (`userOutline = InputUser.AddComponent<Outline>();
        userOutline.effectColor = Color.red;
        userOutline.effectDistance = new Vector2(3,-3);`) and the text next to the "Save" button is displayed (enabled). The next click on "Save" checks everything again and disables the Outline and the text if everything's okay.